# How to Tell if There Are Processes Waiting in a Semaphore in C

Tags: c, semaphore

Is there any way to check if there are processes waiting inside a semaphore in C? I'm using `semaphore.h` to implement semaphores, which you can find the man page for [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/semaphore.h.html).

`sem_getvalue(sem_t * semaphoreToCheck, int * whereToStoreValue)` allows you to get the current value inside `semaphoreToCheck` and store it inside `whereToStoreValue`, but `sem_getvalue` will always store `0` in `whereToStoreValue` if there are any processes waiting inside `semaphoreToCheck` on Linux-based systems.

In semaphore.h, though, semaphores won't add processes to its waiting queue until its value becomes negative. This makes it impossible to determine if processes are waiting in `semaphoreToCheck` using `sem_getvalue` since it will store `0` in `whereToStoreValue` when the value inside `semaphoreToCheck` is 0 *and* when the value inside `semaphoreToCheck` is negative (which means there are processes in the semaphore's waiting queue).

To clarify, my program has a loop, and as part of this loop, I sometimes need to release one process. However, I cannot release more than one process at a time for program requirement reasons. As a result, I need to ensure that the semaphore only gets signaled when there is a process waiting in its queue. This prevents the semaphore's value from becoming greater than `0`, and that ensures that a process will never be able to run without first queuing into the semaphore.

Comment: One process, one unit.  Create another 'ProcessAvailable' semaphore, initialized to 1, that your 'program' waits on before  it releases a process semaphore unit. When a work process exits, it posts the unit back to PA as its last action.   Will that do,  because your plan of 'inspecting' a semaphore will not work:(

Comment: BTW, C does not have semaphores, they are a synchro primitive supplied by your OS.  You may wish to retag to 'multithreaded' or 'operating systems'.